# How to add key value pair to all objects in an array with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I'm looping through an array of objects, each of which has a nested array of objects:

```
_each(this.props.chartProps.data, function(item){
    //item.values is an array of objects
    });
```

I want to add the same key value pair to all of the objects within the nested array. In other words, all of the objects in item.values should have a new key value pair added, call it `newpair`.

I'd like to clone it.

Is there a quick lodashian way to do this?

Comment: if you use react it's not a good idea to mutate your props

Comment: In vanilla: `item.values = item.values.map(value => { value.foo = bar; return value; })` ?

Comment: @gcampbell Why you're cloning the array?

Comment: Then just use `forEach` instead? `item.values.forEach( o => o[key] = "value");`

Comment: I used map as well. I am not trying to mutate the array, should have said, but make a clone lke the above.

Comment: I wonder why lodash is still used for this stuff.

Comment: I thought maybe a non-vanilla way would make easier. Turns out I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you want to mutate the inner objects, or (shallow) clone them before adding the key/value? Do you want the result to be the new value of *item.values*, or do you want it stored elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
function modify(o) { /* set prop here */}

var objects = _.flatMap(array, function(o) { return o.values; });
_.forEach(objects, modify);
```

Answer (score 4):

I used a straightforward map array prototype method:

```js
item.values = item.values.map(value => { value.foo = bar; return value; });
```

Comment: In this way you are mutating the array, not clear if it's what OP wanted

Comment: Probably you can do `value => ({foo: bar, ...value})`